# SSRS sub-report fails locally but works fine on the server and co-worker's machine

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

My co-worker is changing the sub-report used in the report that I am developing. Since I got the latest changes my report displays the following error in place of a sub-report:

```
Data retrieval failed for the subreport, 'sub1', located at: /sub1. Please check the log files for more information.
```

The changes are too numerous to post them here or describe. Parameters have changed. Lots of formatting changes, expression and value changes, etc.

VS displays this in the error window:

```
Warning 1
[rsErrorExecutingSubreport] An error occurred while executing the subreport 'sub1' (Instance: 401iT1R0R0R0x0S0):
Data retrieval failed for the subreport, 'sub1', located at: /sub1.
Please check the log files for more information.
[rsNone] Data retrieval failed for the subreport, 'sub1', located at: /sub1.
C:\Workspace\Reports\Statement.rdl  0   0
```

But when I upload my report to the server where the sub-report is deployed, the report works fine. The co-worker developed another report where this sub-report is used. That report works fine both on the server and on their machine, but not on my machine.

If I try to run the sub-report itself, it displays error:

```
An error occurred during local report processing.
An error occurred during report processing.
```

This report uses 4 more sub-reports developed by my co-worker and all of them display on the report fine and run standalone just fine, locally or on the server.

What items should I check? Not familiar with this situation as usually it is the opposite - works locally but not on the server. Thanks!

Comment: Have him send you the .rdl for the subreport, i think its having a problem on your PC because it doesn't have the latest version of the subreport like his does.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but we do not do that. They check in the code and deploy to the server, I get the latest version from TFS. Have to follow this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the problem escalated to my co-worker's machine over the last few hours, the co-worker just found a solution: open the sub-report, go to Report Data tab, edit the Data Source, go to Credentials, switch from "Use this user name and password" to "Prompt for credentials", then switch back, click OK button, switch to Preview and see the sub-report working.

That does not make a change and saving is not required, but it fixes the whatever error VS2012 may have created internally and saved somewhere in registry or internal files (which is evident from the fact that deleting `.data` files, restarting VS or rebooting machine would not fix the error condition).

Boo, Microsoft! Boo! This is a new bug in 2012 vs 2008 BI Studio.